# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку

Tags: c#

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл
```

При запуске через Visual Studio всё работает, но если запустить exe-шник вне папки проекта, выдает эту ошибку. Устанавливал JSON через NuGet, ставил последнюю стабильную версию (12.0.3). Гуглил ошибку, советовали в свойствах установить флаг "копировать локально" в True и проверить наличие референса в csproj файле. Флаг стоит в True, в csproj файле reference с json есть (далее код)

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

В чём моя ошибка? Заранее благодарен

Comment: Вместе с экзешником должна быть `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` в одной папке.

Comment: @Bulson понял, спасибо за ответ, работает

Comment: При компиляции в папку проекта должны и библиотеки из нугетов складываться, причём автоматом. Не знаю, как вы ставили нугет, обычно всё это автоматом происходит, а у вас что-то нет - а значит, возможно, что это вы как-то не так поставили пакет.